# .jar file not working properly

Tags: java, jar

I am recently created a java application that runs completely fine in NetBeans IDE, but if i run the .jar file of the application it does not work properly. Here i am providing two snapshots of my program execution in NetBeans:

Log In Screen
[image: Log In Screen]

Successful Log in
[image: Successful Log in]

Now if i run the .jar file outside the IDE, the program don't do anything after the first one of the above pictures. I mean it does not go forward after the button click event. I don't know what to do now. I also converted the .jar file to .exe but that did not work. Please help.

Comment: may be some errors while packaging ?

Comment: Is it something like : first `Jframe` can't call the second `Jframe`?

Comment: Or can show the code for the button click event?

Answer (score 1):

Log all your steps in code. Something like

```
public void buttonClickMethod() {
    System.out.println("Log in button is clicked. Starting verification process");
    startVerification();
    ....
}
```

After that run you jar from CMD like:

```
java -jar fileName.jar
```

And you will see all steps in your CMD screen. With exceptions and other things. It will help you to diagnose the problem.

Comment: One point can be noted here. When i cleaned and build the project that means when i created the jar file, NetBeans gave me an warning that i have used a deprecated method; but still NetBeans could successfully created the .jar file. I had used readLine() method of DataInputStream class which is deprecated. But still i can run the program completely fine inside the IDE, but not outside of it. Can that cause a problem?

Comment: No. Deprecated method means that you can use it, but this method will be phased out in next versions of library.

Answer (score 0):

try to clean and build project then run your jar file ,maybe work correctly